# Get a constant value from a string in PHP

Tags: php

I need to extract the value of a constant in PHP from a string.
My example will explains it better than my words :)

constants.php :

```
define('CONNECTION_FAILED', 'Connection Error');
```

index.php :

```
include_once 'constants.php';
$success = $_GET['message']; //$success -> "CONNECTION_FAILED"
```

Now what I want to do is to show the value of the constant with the name present on the $success variable.

Do you know a way to do this simple thing ?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can get the value of a constant of computed name with the constant function:

```
define('CONNECTION_FAILED', 'Connection Error');
$success = $_GET['message']; //$success -> 'CONNECTION_FAILED'
$message = constant($success); // 'Connection error'
```

Answer (score 5):

You can use the [`constant`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php) function to get the value of a constant:

```
define("MAXSIZE", 100);

echo MAXSIZE;
echo constant("MAXSIZE"); // same thing as the previous line
```

In your case it can be:

```
echo constant($success);
```

Answer (score 1):

See `constant` http://dk.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php 
ou can do `constant($success)`

Answer (score 1):

Using `constant()`, you can achieve what you want. Check that its set before you do anything to avoid having *Undefined constant* notices.

```
include_once 'constants.php';
$success = '';
if (isset($_GET['message']) && constant($_GET['message']) !== null) {
    $success = constant($_GET['message']);
} else {
    // Not a valid message
    // $_GET['message'] not defined as a constant's name
}
```

- http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.constant.php